# How to insert an HTML5 audio/video autoplay tag in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html5-video, html5-audio, google-translate

I am trying to use AngularJS for a personal project.

The idea is to generate a number (or later words) and have the text-to-speech URL from Google translate to read it. Then You have to write what was said.

I succeeded to make it works, but I don't know what happened, it doesn't work anymore.

Here is a link to the project:
https://github.com/Polopollo/numberProject

Here is the file that poses me some problems:
https://github.com/Polopollo/numberProject/blob/master/app/scripts/services/soundgenerator.js

I duplicate the content here:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('languageTrainerApp').provider('soundgenerator', function(){

//in case of we want to change the API to generate a sound file from a text
this.defaultTextToSpeechUrl = 'http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&tl=en&q=';

this.$get = function() {
    //to escape the error to be able to write on multiple lines
    /*jshint multistr: true */

    //here is our service which will have a method to generate the player to insert
    var soundgenerator = {
        'generatePlayer': function (textToRead) {
            var res = '\
                <audio controls autoplay>\
                  <source src="https://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&tl=en&q='+textToRead+'" type="audio/mpeg">\
                  Your browser does not support the audio element.\
                </audio>';
            return res;
        }
    };

    return soundgenerator;
    };
});
```

And I try to inject it in the "main.js":

```
//why this doesn't work..?
$scope.HTML5AudioPlayer = $sce.trustAsHtml(soundgenerator.generatePlayer("A text to read"));
```

I would like to get all informations on what is incorrect, including how my provider should be written if it is badly written, but mostly to make the audio player works!

Comment: If you want to see a preview, here it is: http://paulvayssiere.com/project-number/

Comment: Ok the problem was while I coded, the Google's TTS stopped working with a cross-domain ajax.

It doesn't even work with Jquery either if I try to inject it. (but it still works if the audio tag is present with the good src audio file with the page loads. No idea why yet.

Comment: Indeed sorry, here was the new link, thanks: http://paulvayssiere.com/foreign-language-listening-comprehension/